# how to prevent react clear input field when update the view

Tags: reactjs

In my project there has a form to deal with some verification for cellphone, so I have two input field; one you need to fill in your cellphone number, the other you have to fill in the verification code what you get by SMS and also have a timer to count verification code's lifetime, here is the problem I get...I use `setState()` to update timer and dispaly it on the view, but when it update all my input field will be **clear** and **unfocus**.

Is there a method to **prevent react not to update the input field just update my timer?**

*I know I can use **onChange** and **state** to prcoess and reacord, but can't keep input field `onFocus()`, and I don't think it is a good way.

[code](https://gist.github.com/p208p2002/22bc012d5e4d3cc0f97c243adec58c85)

[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPv2a.jpg)

Comment: can you share some code? what you did?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063824/i-am-trying-to-increase-the-count-value-on-button-click-it-works-but-the-value-i/49063890#49063890

Comment: @illiteratewriter
I post the code [here](https://gist.github.com/p208p2002/22bc012d5e4d3cc0f97c243adec58c85) ...do some modify and commit, please focus and start on line 113, thank for your help :D

Comment: @illiteratewriter and here is what the view like [imgurl](https://imgur.com/a/DhxSK)

Comment: Did not look at all the code, but you're declaring local SFC's, which can explain the behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342535/why-a-child-components-state-keeps-clearing/49342873#49342873

Comment: @Oblosys you solve my question! thanks for help:DD